# ImportError: No module named pbr after pip install successfully

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been using the following command line to instll prb package locally,

pip install -t /data/python3.4/site-packages/  /data/pythonlibs/pbr-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

The process successfully. Afterwards, when I type `import pbr`, it still fails. What can be the possible reason for this failed installation process?

[image]

Comment: Your `pip` symlink points to 3.x interpreter. You are trying to use 2.x interpreter. 2.x and 3.x binaries are independent, you need to install package in correct interpreter before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to not be accounting for Python 2.x and Python 3.x being entirely *separate* environments.

First, you are installing like this:

```
pip install -t /data/python3.4/site-packages/ /data/pythonlibs/pbr-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Unless you are currently inside a virtualenv, the `pip` command will generally be part of the Python 2.x environment. The Python 3 installer is usually `pip3`.

But you are telling this pip to install in `/data/python3.4` - okay, perhaps that can work since you specified where to install.

However, you then run Python 2.6.6, and attempt to load the module which you clearly intended to install into Python 3.x.

You may simply need to run `python3` instead of `python` for this to work.

If that does not do it, then install the module again using `pip3` instead of `pip` and then see if it will work.